# How does haskell-platform use Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, haskell-platform

The page: https://www.haskell.org/platform/ claims that haskell-platform comes with the Stack tool. However, on my Debian system after installing the haskell-platform package, I do not have the command `stack` available to me (which I would if I followed the instructions for installing Stack from the Stack website).

I can't find any information on how Stack is included in haskell-platform. It seems to be mentioned on the front page of the site, and no where else.

So, in what way is Stack "included" with the haskell-platform?

Comment: Frankly, you'd be better off simply installing stack and not bothering with HP at all nowadays

Comment: Sure, I do use stack, and will stick with it. But I'm curious.

Comment: Are you 100% positive that `stack.exe` isn't present anywhere on your system? Maybe it's just a PATH issue.

Comment: Complete guess: Maybe Debian ships older version of platform. Did you install via package manager ? If yes, then what version did it install ?

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking :D

Comment: @Sibi - I installed it via Debian's package manager (version 2014.2.0.0.debian4). Clearly it's quite old... Since when was Stack included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haskell platform 2014.2.0 version doesn't come up with Stack. You can verify it from here: https://www.haskell.org/platform/contents.html

Haskell platform 8.0.1 is the first version which supports Stack. Also the versioning scheme of the platform seemed to change after 2014.2.0.

In my opinion, you should generally not try installing from Debian's package manager as it is usually quite old. Also, these days I would just recommend you to use Stack and install it from [here](https://haskell-lang.org/get-started).

Comment: Mystery solved! And yes, I do use stack. I just found out about haskell-platform and was curious (the install instructions from haskell-platform explicitly said to use Debian's package manager as well :( ). Thanks.